# HttpModule is breaking PostBack events

Tags: asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication, httpmodule

I'm trying to setup a simple HttpModule to handle authentication between my single sign on server. I've included code for the module below. The module is hitting my SSO and properly authenticating; however, on pages with forms the postback events are not occurring properly (e.g. isPostBack value is always false even though a POST occurred, button click events don't get hit, etc.).

```
public sealed class MyAuthenticationModule : IHttpModule
{      
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.AuthenticateRequest += OnAuthenticateRequest;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public static void OnAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.Initialize();

        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        HttpRequest request = context.Request;
        HttpResponse response = context.Response;

        // Validate the ticket coming back from the authentication server
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request["ticket"]))
        {
            // I can include code for this if you want, but it appears to be
            // working correct as whenever I get a ticket from my SSO it is processed
            // correctly. I only get a ticket after coming from the SSO server and
            // then it is removed from the URL so this only gets hit once.
            MyAuthentication.ProcessTicketValidation();
        }

        if (!request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // redirect to the login server
            response.Redirect("https://sso.example.com/login.aspx" + "?" + "service=" + 
                                HttpUtility.UrlEncode(context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri), false);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I would also like to note that if I change the line:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request["ticket"]))
```

to:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.QueryString["ticket"]))
```

the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your postbacks have a duplicate form data variable, "ticket"?  That would seem to explain the behavior to me.

Aside from that, this line is suspicous:

FormsAuthentication.Initialize();

The FormsAuthentication class uses the "Provider" pattern, which means it's a singleton.  You should not re-initialize.  [From the msdn documentation:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.initialize.aspx)

> The Initialize method is called when the FormsAuthenticationModule
>   creates an instance of the FormsAuthentication class. This method is
>   not intended to be called from your code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This didn't fix the problem, but I'll go ahead and remove it anyway.

Comment: revised my answer to address the actual question...see first line??  I think that's about all I have...

Comment: Good thought, but this unfortunately wasn't the problem either.

Comment: This makes me think though, is this causing a problem because the form data collection is being accessed before the something in the Page lifecycle is happening related to postbacks?